# Where can I get a battery for an old(ish) laptop in Lima?

Tags: short-notice, lima

I'm staying in Lima for a short while, and I want to buy a replacement battery for my laptop (a Lenovo X201). I can get a new one delivered from China, but that would take much more time than I have here. Is there somewhere in Lima which stocks such items so I could either go there directly, or somewhere out of Lima but which could have it delivered to where I'm staying within a few days?

Note: Not looking for a zillion-dollar special-air-courier delivery or something like that.

Comment: You can always [replace the lithium cells](https://www.instructables.com/id/HOW-TO-REPAIR-LAPTOP-BATTERY-/) of the old battery in case you couldn't find a new one.

Comment: @NeanDerThal: 1. I don't have the materials, the tools and probably not the time. 2. A bunch of comments suggest this doesn't necessarily work.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be an electronics market, [Cyberplaza](http://limacitykings.com/cyberplaza-lima-electronics-market/) which may have what you need, depending on your luck and how standard that battery is.

If you are staying at a hotel they may be able to suggest sources (including online but in-country to avoid any customs hassle).

[MercadoLibre](https://www.mercadolibre.com.pe) looks to be one of the major online platforms (search lenovo bateria), no idea personally how reliable the sellers there are.

Comment: Taking the first listing I found on mercadolibre points to https://amptechnology.negocio.site which is a computer repair a shop in Miraflores, Lima alleging to have such a battery. OP could probably do the same with other listings to find alternatives.